# What is the gender of poolhouse

Tags: genre

I have seen both genders used for poolhouse, mostly masculine but usually loanwords seem to be unambiguously masculine. Which is it?

Comment: Did you actually see the English word "poolhouse" in French? Do you have examples?

Comment: For some reason, [*house*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/house) is feminine, while [*penthouse*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/penthouse) is masculine. This is undoubtedly why people are confused about the gender of *poolhouse*.

Comment: @PeterShor [club-house](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/club-house) is also masculine.

Answer (score 1):

Mot d'origine anglaise, on pourrait dire que chacun lui donne le genre de son choix. Néanmoins, dans le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/poolhouse), on trouve :

> poolhouse \pul.aws\ masculin
>
> (Anglicisme) (Architecture) Pavillon ou kiosque de piscine. Construction dédiée à l’agrément ou à l’entretien d’une piscine.
> Dans le jardin situé à l’arrière de la maison il y avait une piscine et un poolhouse. — (Mathieu Croizet, Polka, 2010)
> Et qui dit piscine, dit poolhouse. — (Ivo Pauwels, Dépendances en chêne, 2005)